# iPhone app based on GPS

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps

Will the GPS cordinates be accurate enough to build an app which helps the user to navigate inside a building? Ex: to give path to the EXIT, to give path to navigate to a wash room, different section etc?

Comment: You'll never know unless you try to test yourself ;) Personally I'd say that gps won't work for that as gps signal inside buildings is usually very bad (if any). Although in my place gps coverage is poor - it may be different in US or EU...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in all buildings GPS even work, and, when outside, it is not precise enough without additional stations.
Typical GPS precision is 10-12 meters.

Comment: You could try to go with the WLAN location, though, which should automatically be considered when querying the location in iOS. The resolution of this method strongly depends on the number of access points around, though. I have made the experience, that it can be surprisingly precise, but most probably not enough for turn-based directions in a building.